# Modules missing when installing python project using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

I'm deploying my first python project, but having issues with installation. I've followed the practices outlined in https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi. My project is organized with a top-level executable script `bin/gsat` that calls imports other modules like so:

`import gsat.input_validation as input_validation`

The modules are in `src/gsat/` , following the arrangement in the example project at https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject

If I install locally from the project source , using develop mode:

`pip install -e .`

... then I have no issues installing and the software works.

But if I install it from PyPI:

`pip install "gsat"`

... then it won't run because the import statements fail to find the modules. Error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/gsat", line 10, in <module>
    import gsat.input_validation as input_validation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gsat'
```

The full project is at https://github.com/MikeAxtell/gsat , commit c680172. The project is also on PyPI as "gsat". The distribution files are being made like:

`python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

... and the fun setup.py file is below. I'm sure this is some noob issue; I am new to python packaging and python programming in general, so thanks in advance for help!

setup.py:

```
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="gsat", 
    version="0.1a",
    author="Michael J. Axtell",
    author_email="mja18@psu.edu",
    description="General Small RNA-seq Analysis Tool",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/MikeAxtell/gsat",
    scripts=['bin/gsat'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='gsat'),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>3.5, <4',
    install_requires=['biopython','python-Levenshtein'],
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue in this line:

`packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='gsat'),`

I believe it should read the following instead:

`packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='src'),`